# Better list of open programs from EnumWindows

Tags: c#, windows, user32

Right, I already know how to get a list of all running processes with EnumWindows, however this doesn't give me a 'pretty' result like Task Manager. With the result from EnumWindows I clean it to only show visible windows with a text name etc... but this seems to include thinks like "cortana", "start" and "Windows Shell Experience Host" which aren't in Task Manager. How can I thin these out further from my result?

Additional question, how can I get the AppIcon from programs. In task manager the programs Icon is displayed next to their name, how could I retrieve this?

Comment: *"I already know how to get a list of all running processes with EnumWindows"* - `EnumWindows` enumerates top-level windows. While every window belongs to a process, not all processes have windows, and some have more than one top-level window. *"How can I thin these out further from my result?"* - By filtering based on arbitrarily chosen criteria.

Comment: And that criteria is? Currently, I remove all result that are not visible or have a window text length of 0 but I still get results that still get through, like "start" and "cortana". This is for use in a NodeJS module so I'm not sure if you'll find it useful but [this](https://github.com/MrTimcakes/node-hide/blob/master/main.js#L34) where I process the results.

Comment: You've already arbitrary decided to only account for processes that have top-level windows. You can pick an equally arbitrary criteria to filter out the entries you don't like. I don't know what makes Notepad or Chrome more desirable than Start or Cortana, so you will have to come up with the filter criteria yourself.

Comment: @IInspectable: I think the implicit question here is "what criteria does Task Manager use"?

Comment: This is just a guess, but perhaps you want to check the [window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx)?  Most "proper" windows would have `WS_CAPTION` set, for example.